# 500 error on phpmyadmin export on /phpmyadmin/export.php

Tags: 14.04, phpmyadmin

I'm getting a HTTP ERROR 500 when attempting to export from phpmyadmin. It only occurs after hitting the 'export' button after setting all the export settings. I'm able to do a mysqlbackup just fine, but I get an error on export.php.

I'm not really sure where to start with this, there are no errors in any log that I checked. I've uninstalled, purged and reinstalled phpmyadmin with no change. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm running php7.0 on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php`

On line 864 : change `break 2;` by `break;`

Source : [github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11912)

Worked for me ;)

Comment: Such a simple solution for a problem that has been driving me nuts for months! Works great, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help ;)

Comment: Working for me too :)

Comment: omg finally!!! after one year i found the sslution

Comment: you're a hero, thumbs up man!

Comment: Hah, great tip. Why phpmyadmin have errors like this? You save me man.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić because the devs forgot to update their code for PHP 7 compatibility.

Comment: @GuillaumeLeMière OMG! PHP7 many peoples now use and phpMyAdmin not made support for it?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić well, I just looked at their code on github and can't find any occurence of "break 2" in export.php. The file is also shorter so I guess the team fixed this issue a long time ago, but the ppa repo probably didn't get updated since then on ubuntu 14.
No problem on ubuntu 16 by installing it using default ppa.
You can trust versions 4.5.4 and above.